# What is this through-hole component holder used on aluminum PCBs?

Tags: pcb, connector, soldering, surface-mount, light

I've been buying these cheaps LED lightbulbs and tore them down to see how the LEDs are driven.

On all of them I have found this surface mount component that allows a through hole component (here a capacitor and wires) to be attached, apparently without soldering.

I imagine that they use that because it's an aluminum PCB and therefore plated vias cannot be used.

[image]
[image]

I also found a really interesting one that allows another PCB to be connected at a right angle.

[image]
[image]

Do you know what is the name of these components? I'd like to buy some on Digikey.

Comment: I don't think the PCB is aluminum.  The aluminum you see is just a heat sink that is bonded to the standard FR4 (or similar) PCB.

Comment: They're connectors specifically designed for this kind of application and I don't think you will find them at Digikey. If you need production quantities, they're available from China sources (with UL approvals).

Comment: @SteveSh It's an aluminum core PCB. You can get them in single layer and even double layer (though single is most common). Even in prototype quantities from suppliers such as pcbway. [Construction](https://pcbwayfile.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/web/20/04/30/1728371983538.png)

Comment: @Sephro - Thanks for the info.  But it looks to me like the aluminum has cutouts to allow parts to attached to the PCB beneath.

Comment: @SteveSh The cutouts are punched (in a punch  press, with hard tooling- dies), along with the outline. The right-angle board is an ordinary PCB, no aluminum. The dielectric is often ceramic filled to give additional thermal conductivity. [Here](https://www.epectec.com/downloads/Aluminum-Material-List.pdf) is an excellent list of typical Al (and Cu) PCB materials with relevant specs.

Comment: If you don't care about extreme cost optimization, some bulbs will instead pass normal insulated wires from the power supply board to the LED board.  This is presumably more expensive in volume, but has the advantage of allowing you to more completely decouple the (heat sensitive) capacitors from the hot LED board.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what this connector is? I've opened up a few downlights that have a 2x2 and 2x4 version of the 2x1 connector you took photos of, but still haven't found them. I have an aluminium PCB I'm working on and can't solder wires in my application. A connector like this would be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

AVX (now Kyocera) makes very similar clips to the ones in the 3rd and 4th picture, but for wire, not for PCBs.

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/kyocera-avx/709296001103006/4806550

[image: Kyocera 709296001103006]